# PostgreSQL GREATEST with NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Using PostgreSQL, I am looking for something like `SELECT GREATEST(0,x)` where x can be `NULL`. In case `x IS NULL`, the query should return `NULL`, similar to MySQL and Google BigQuery and not `0` which is the standard behavior in PostgreSQL. Is there an easy way to accomplish this without cases and conditions?

`SELECT GREATEST(0,NULL)` should return NULL, not 0

In the official documentation:

> The GREATEST and LEAST functions select the largest or smallest value
>   from a list of any number of expressions. The expressions must all be
>   convertible to a common data type, which will be the type of the
>   result (see Section 10.5 for details). NULL values in the list are
>   ignored. The result will be NULL only if all the expressions evaluate
>   to NULL.
>
> Note that GREATEST and LEAST are not in the SQL standard, but are a
>   common extension. Some other databases make them return NULL if any
>   argument is NULL, rather than only when all are NULL.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-conditional.html

I'm looking for a GREATEST function that does not ignore NULLs

Comment: Any particular reason for using such an old version of PostgreSQL? I wouldn't be surprised if it's no longer supported

Comment: I'm using this version: PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: Would you expect NULL for `greatest(1,2,null,4,5)` as well?

Comment: correct, the expected behavior is greatest(1,2,null) should return NULL

Comment: Updated the question to use the correct version number in both tag, URL and description.

Comment: Do you want it to work just for 2 numbers/columns?

Comment: just 2 for now.

Comment: You could use a case expression and test for something like `case when 0 + 1 + null + 2 is null then null else greatest(0, 1, null, 2) end`

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own function:

```
create function strange_greatest(variadic p_input int[])
  returns int
as
$$
  select v
  from unnest(p_input) as t(v)
  order by t desc nulls first
  limit 1;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

```
postgres=> select strange_greatest(1,2,4);
strange_greatest
----------------
               4
(1 row)

postgres=> select strange_greatest(1,2,null,4);
strange_greatest
----------------

(1 row)
```

Comment: BTW, why *strange*? How is it possible that the *greatest* number is *greater than NULL*? Anyway I agree that the `GREATEST` implementation in PostgreSQL is *meaningfull* and often *handy*, but somehow *inconsistent* e.g. with `null` string handling... Maybe I'm missing something;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: `greatest()` applies the same rules as `max()` - I find that consistent.

Answer (score 3):

You could add another expression.  For numbers:

```
select greatest(a, b, c) + (a + b + c - (a + b + c))
```

This is a bit more challenging for other data types.  But arrays can help:

```
select greatest(a, b, c) * nullif( array_position(array[a, b, c], null) is not null), true )::int
```

Answer (score 2):

For the case of 2 numbers (columns), if your table is like this:

```
create table tablename(a int, b int);

insert into tablename(a, b) values
(10, 20), (null, 30), (40, null);
```

then use the function `greatest()` like this:

```
select 
  greatest((a + b) - b, (a + b) - a) "greatest"
from tablename;
```

If `a` or `b` is `null` then both expressions: `(a + b) - b` and `(a + b) - a` are `null` and the function `greatest()` will return `null`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vM6kU9diayRsmZVcvEjhBB/2).
Results:

```
| greatest |
| -------- |
| 20       |
| null     |
| null     |
```